# logstash _grokparsefailure for realy simple tag

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I don't understand why I have a grokparse failure for this simple config :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/*.log"
    codec => json {
    }
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    add_tag => ["test"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
      /.../
  }
}
```

The logs are correcly sent to elasticsearch, the json is correcly parsed, but the added tag don't work, instead I have a tag "_grokparsefailure". What I want is to pass a static value as a tag.

I am surely missing something dumb, but I can't find what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `grok` filter does nothing, there is no pattern to match, the tag would only be applied after a successful match.

To add a tag in your case you can use the `tags` option in your input or the `mutate` filter.

To use the `tags` option just add change your input to this one:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/*.log"
    codec => json
    tags => ["test"] 
  }
}
```

To use the `mutate` filter, put the bellow config inside your `filter` block.

```
mutate {
    add_tag => ["test"]
}
```

Both configurations will add a `test` tag to all your messages.